# VideoView onBufferingUpdate() not getting called?

Tags: android, buffering, android-videoview

I want to allow only 20% of the video to be buffered. But for some reason my onBufferingUpdate() is not getting called.

Any reason?
I am trying to play .m3u8 on VideoView. The video gets played but onBufferingUpdate() is not getting called.

This is my below code

```
String VideoURL =     "http://devimages.apple.com/iphone/samples/bipbop/gear1/prog_index.m3u8"
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.videoview_main);

    videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);

    pDialog = new ProgressDialog(VideoViewActivity.this);
    pDialog.setTitle("Android Video Streaming POC");
    pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
    pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
    pDialog.setCancelable(false);
    pDialog.show();

    try {
        // Start the MediaController
        MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
            VideoViewActivity.this);
        mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
        // Get the URL from String VideoURL
        Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
        videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
        videoview.setVideoURI(video);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    videoview.requestFocus();
    videoview.setOnPreparedListener(VideoViewActivity.this);
}

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
    pDialog.dismiss();
    mp.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(new OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
        // show updated information about the buffering progress
        @Override
        public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
            Log.e("ERRORRRRRRRRRR", "percent: " + percent);
        }
    });
    videoview.start();
}
```

Suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: What Android version are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the listener after calling start() on the MediaPlayer.

Answer (score 0):

I think it's because it's an HLS Video, have you tried with a progressive HTTP download ?
[Test mp4](http://mirrorblender.top-ix.org/movies/sintel-1024-surround.mp4)
I tried with this one and I can se that is called, I also called .start() after .setVideoURI() and not in the onPrepared.